# How to get UTC time from local time (without date) in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I've an object where elements are like

i) `"StartTime":"0001-01-01T09:30:00+00:00"` and `"Timezone":"NEW YORK"`

The time string is a 24hour format and where `"+00:00"` is meaningless i.e. hard coded for all timezone.

I've to convert it to UTC time.

My code-

```
$startTime = new \DateTime(substr($obj->Session->StartTime, 0, -6));
$startTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
print_r($startTime);
DateTime Object
(
[date] => 0001-01-01 03:36:40
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => UTC
)
```

But it should be actually 2:30 pm?

ii) `"StartTime":"0001-01-01T08:00:00+00:00"` and `"Timezone":"LONDON"`

Results to

```
DateTime Object
(
[date] => 0001-01-01 02:06:40
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => UTC
)
```

It's wrong again.

Any help please?

Comment: I don't think it can be solved directly from the input string I mentioned. I've solved this using City, Country, Region and Global Region mapping database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a solution like NTP (network time protocol). It will be very accurate, as well as come with many tools for manipulation and time zone conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I'd solved it using city / region table mapped to its valid timezone. From that local timezone I convert the time to UTC. e.g. LON is mapped to Europe/London.

Comment: glad you solved it. still seems overly complex imho.